# DataGrid not showing focus for SelectedItem when ViewModel is redisplayed

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid, focus

`PersonsViewModel` has a corresponding DataTemplate with a DataGrid bound to `PersonList`. `DataGrid.SelectedItem` has two-way databinding to `SelectedPerson`, so that when I select a row in the view, the corresponding item from `PersonList` is assigned to `SelectedPerson`.

It works fine except for one problem: when I switch screens, say, to `PersonDetailScreen`, and come back, the selection focus is lost! I mean, `SelectedPerson` still contains its former value, but the DataGrid comes out visually unselected.

I made a test, creating a two-way databound "SelectedIndex" in viewmodel. Then, I can see the actual selection is still present in viewmodel when it comes back, the problem seems to be:

"How to focus the `SelectedIndex` of an `ItemsControl` when ViewModel's datatemplate is loaded and some "SelectedIndex" databound property in such viewmodel already contains a value?"

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `TwoWay Binding` then you can set the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` value from your view model. I'm a little bit confused as to your set up though... when you say '*when I switch screens ... and come back, the selection focus is lost*', it sounds a bit like you're keeping the view model alive, but not the view? I'm more used to displaying a fresh view each time, but the fix would be the same either way.

Now if this were one of my views, I'd load the data into any collections from the constructor and (internally in a base class) set the `CurrentItem` property that is data bound to the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property to the first item in the collection. You should do the same, except that instead of setting it to the first item, you'd set it to whichever item was last selected.

So the answer is just to set the `SelectedItem` property each time the view is displayed. However, if you're saying that the `SelectedItem` property is already set to the item that should be selected, you may need to set it to any other value first and then set it back to the correct item.

Comment: Hi, what I do is actually to switch viewmodels. I don't even have views, the datagrid is in a DataTemplate whose DataType is the given viewmodel. So, when I set the, say, "WindowContent" property with said viewmodel, the view "pops up" automatically, being a fresh one every time. It's a very intentional ViewModel-First approach from my part.

Comment: Your last paragraph is interesting... In code behind, I could force some things to happen (WPF lacks some trivial behaviours, it seems to me...), but that would need a specific refactoring: thinning down my datatemplates to only contain references to more thick, code-behind filled UserControls.

Comment: That's not necessarily true... you can use MVVM and leave your code behind code free. All the same, I'd still recommend that you use one `UserControl` (view with the contents of your `DataTemplate`) per view model... you can still keep your view model first approach, but it will just be easier to maintain view files than a bunch of `DataTemplate`s.

Comment: I believe we agree here: datatemplates are a good way to have ViewModelFirst, through their DataType. But INSIDE datatemplates we can put our plain old Views right away (in the form of UserControl subclasses with variable amount of code behind). I've seen this pattern in more than a bunch of tutorials and SO examples...

Answer (score 0):

What are we talking about here, item selection or item focus?

If you want a visual item to get focus when a template is rendered, your best bet is to set the focus manually in your xaml's code behind, by, say, hooking a handler to your page's 'Loaded' event and setting the focus manually to your datagrid by calling on its 'Focus()' method.

I know this breaks some MVVM rules, but focus management is highly dependent on your page's visual tree, and thus cannot be properly modeled through a viewmodel, which should be as view-independent as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The ViewModel keeps logic state of which element is selected, and that works. The selection itself works, because if I debug (breakpoint) the selected item and selected index are still set to the proper value. Problem is: the VISUAL state of the DataGrid is like anything is selected (every rows are equal, having an "unselected" state. It's not that the control doesnt have focus, is that the row that should be displayed as selected has the same look as every other row, even if the datagrid itself has focus.

Comment: Quick question. When you leave the Persons view to go to another screen, and then go back to it, is the PersonsViewModel the same instance as before or do you create it again?

Comment: Related question. If the PersonsViewModel is the same instance, are  you maybe repopulating your PersonList? what could be happening is that the SelectedPerson was an item from an original PersonList. If you at any moment repopulate the PersonList with new instances of Person, then, even though the SelectedPerson still holds a Person instance, this instance is no longer in PersonList, and your datagrid cannot find the selected person in its ItemSource.

Comment: The instance is the same. It is actually a property of a parentViewModel which is the MainWindow's DataContext. MainWindow and parentViewModel have a single instance while program is running, and I switch parentViewModel.CurrentScreen with its long-living ScreenViewModel instances. What happens is that DataGrid in View is recreated every time, having a "SelectedIndex" with two-way databinding to a corresponding property in ViewModel...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sheridan's insights, I have solved the problem easier than I imagined, and somewhat unintentionally.

I had the DataGrid defined directly in a DataTemplate. When the template loaded, I BELIEVE, although I am not sure at all, that some initialization step required to pass the "SelectedItem" or "SelectedItem" value to the View was "lost".

I planned to do this re-selection manually in code behind, so what I did was to move the datagrid to some UserControl I created from scratch. But then, the very fact that the DataTemplate now instantiates a proper View (derived from UserControl) inside itself, which in turn contains the datagrid, seems to "make more notifications work", so to say, and the View displays selected row like it always should.

So, now I have this in my DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="PersonScreenTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:PersonScreenViewModel}">   
    <vw:PersonScreenViewView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

That seems to be the perfect pure-WPF design pattern for ViewModel-first: a datatemplate whose content is a single usercontrol, which in turn declares and binds and handles everything.